# Bluesky statistics hanging when opening file

Tags: statistics

When trying to load a data file BlueSky hangs up. How do I escape when it does this? Hitting the esc key doesn't work. I have to reboot, which loses everything I've done up to that point.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use R code directly to load/open a file (e.g. CSV) into a data frame instead, to see if this is working.
Make sure to add the data frame to the “data grid”
so you can access it as a table on the GUI level.
Here I made an example to load directly from a SQLite database file: https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/9e85be8eaaa2416e992a386e994fc327518e79e4dd08befb994e126a97a91b18